# how to generate 70V AC from TLP222G-2

Tags: ac, pwm, inverter, opto-isolator, h-bridge

I have 70VDC 30mA source

I need to control optoisolators **to generate** **70V AC** signal

I can use [TLP222g-2](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/318800/ToshibaSemiconductor/TLP222G/1) dual isolators. to build the h bridge

I have a **single PWM channel** from my MCU.

Is it possible to use i**nverting logic CMOS (CMOS NOT) ic to inverter PWM signal** and apply to the isolator control inputs which should be switched of as in h bridge configuration?

which inverting CMOS ic would be perfect for this?

**Jasen** is what you said?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an inverter, just connect the optocoupler inputs between signal and VDD instead of between signal and VSS.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZqXHg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
Shown as LEDs these are the start of the optocouplers.

Comment: i did not get **connect the optocoupler inputs between signal and VDD**

Comment: which of those three terms is confusing you?

Comment: its not about the terms, I'm gonna need 2 of tlp222g-2 and how to perform your method? I have 4x Optocoupler inputs to control in order to generate AC signal

Comment: two go up, two go down.

Comment: what is **between** mean? in "connect the optocoupler inputs between signal and VDD" signal is 5V PWM  and  Vdd is again 5V.... how two go up two go down here? can you show in a diagram it is hard to imagine what you have explained

Comment: I can't think of better words. I have added a picture.